# 'XXX.rb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows-7, ruby

Installed Ruby without a hitch, installed ruby gems, ensured the environment variables path have C:\Ruby25-x64\bin in them, wrote a script went to run the script and received the following: "'XXX.rb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." What else do I need to do? Had ruby 1.9.3 running on this computer several years ago, had similar problem but the environment variables path resolved it, then.

Comment: See this related question on StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422380/how-to-i-launch-a-ruby-script-from-the-command-line-by-just-its-name